# Get 'Can't resolve all parameters' when I provide the Interceptor

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement HttpInterceptor.
When I add it to @NgModule, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for JwtInterceptor: (?, ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15547)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15382)
```

Spent much time on googling, don’t have an idea what to undertake…

Here is how I provide the Interceptor in AppModule:

```
...
providers: [
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true
   }
],
...
```

Here is the Interceptor itself, nothing fancy:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   constructor(private inj: Injector, private logger: Logger) {
      this.logger.l(true)('Interceptor >>');
   }

   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      this.logger.l(true)('interceptor >>');

      const auth = this.inj.get(AuthService);

      // add token to the request:
      const authReq = req.clone({
         setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.getToken()}`
         }
      });

      // return next.handle(authReq);
      return next.handle(authReq).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
         if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // todo: get refreshed token if it exists:
         }
      }, (err: any) => {
         if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
               auth.collectFailedRequest(authReq);
               // todo: redirect to the login route or show a modal
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: have you added `@Injectable()` to your interceptor?

Comment: @Und3rTow , OMG, of course, your right, I haven't! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

My bad, I forgot to add `@Injectable()` to my `interceptor` class.

Comment: I my case still not working even I have @Injectable()

Comment: i added @Injectable() but still get this error : Can't resolve all parameters for HttpErrorInterceptor

Answer (score 1):

> add  @Injectable() in your interceptor file  after import statements

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable() <- add this in your interceptor file ...(maybe you have missed by mistake)

export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router,public toastController: ToastController) {

  }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        event =>  {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // do stuff with response if you want
          }
        },
```